# Removing a sequence of lines

Tags: sed, awk

How can I remove everything from `Part1`, up to `Part2`, including `Part1` and `Part2`, from the following text?

```
ABC
Part1
text
more text
Part2
DEF
```

The result should be:

```
ABC
DEF
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using sed:

```
sed '/Part1/,/Part2/d' filename
```

Answer (score 2):

Using a print flag with `awk`:

```
$ awk '/Part1/{p=1}!p;/Part2/{p=0}' file
ABC
DEF
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
awk '/^Part1/,/^Part2/{next}{print}' file
```